# ArrayList passing by reference with dates object?

Tags: java, arraylist

I pass dates to an `ArrayList` but when I change the `Date` object, all the `Date`s inside the `ArrayList` will change. This is an example:

```
Date currentDate = new Date("6/10/2011");
ArrayList<Date> datesList = new ArrayList();

currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
datesList.add(currentDate);

currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
datesList.add(currentDate);

currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
datesList.add(currentDate);

System.out.println(datesList.toString());
```

This will print:

```
[Mon Jun 13 00:00:00 EDT 2011, Mon Jun 13 00:00:00 EDT 2011, Mon Jun 13 00:00:00 EDT 2011]
```

Any idea of why this happening and how could I solve it?

Comment: Well, what kind of output are you expecting? You pass the reference (to the same object) three times and you end up with a collection that contains that object three times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the variable `currentDate` references a single instance of `Date`, which you have added to the list many times. When you call `currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1)` you're simply updating that same object's state, and every time you call `datesList.add(currentDate)` that same object is added to the `ArrayList`.

Also note that [`setDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setDate%28int%29) and [`getDate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate%28%29) are deprecated methods. You should look into using a [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for date manipulation:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2011, 5, 10);

ArrayList<Date> datesList = new ArrayList<Date>();

datesList.add(cal.getTime());

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
datesList.add(cal.getTime());

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
datesList.add(cal.getTime());

System.out.println( datesList.toString());
```

or better yet, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

You're repeatedly adding references to the same object, so you end up with a list that contains multiple references to that same object.

Try adding copies instead:

```
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1)
datesList.add(currentDate.clone());          // note the .clone()
```

Answer (score 0):

List `datesList` has the same instance in all positions. It's the same `Date` instance instantiated at `Date currentDate = new Date("6/10/2011");`. Try cloning it with `clone()`, and modify & add each clone to the list.

```
   ArrayList<Date> datesList = new ArrayList();

   Date currentDate = new Date("6/10/2011"); ;
   currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);
   datesList.add(currentDate);

   currentDate = currentDate.clone();
   currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);
   datesList.add(currentDate);

   currentDate = currentDate.clone();
   currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);
   datesList.add(currentDate);

   System.out.println( datesList.toString());
```

By doing this, each time you do `currentDate = currentDate.clone()`, you're assigning a **new** instance of `Date` with the same properties to the variable `currentDate`, while not modifying the original instances already added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
int dateNum = 3;
ArrayList<Date> datesList = new ArrayList();

for(int x = 0; x < dateNum; x++){
   Date currentDate = new Date("6/10/2011"); //Creating a new object so your not pointing to the same one in memory
   currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+1);
   datesList.add(currentDate);
}

   System.out.println( datesList.toString());
```